# Can't show popover controller with UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, storyboard, uipopovercontroller

i use storyboard for developing UI for my project. There are many issues were solved, but this problem killing me. I have added action for UIBarButtonItem :

```
- (IBAction)pressAddActionButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
if (_mode == itemSelect) {

    LookUpTableViewController *vc =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"lookupTable"];
    vc.key = @"title";
    vc.data = [Linesheet MR_findAllSortedBy:@"title" ascending:YES];
    vc.lookUpDelegate = self;

    self.myPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
    [self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];      
} else {
    self.mode = itemSelect;
}
```

}

If i using storyBoard segue for showing popover - all good, but if i do it **in runtime a popover does not show**. I should manually create UIBarButtonItem.

Thanks for help!!!

**Update, code for buttons:**

```
- (void)setupNavigationItems {

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

    UIBarButtonItem *addItem;
    if (_mode == itemSelect) {
        addItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                                                                target:self 
                                                                action:@selector(pressAddActionButton:)];   
    } else {
        addItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                                  target:self 
                                                  action:@selector(pressDoneButton:)];
    }
    [addItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];

    UIBarButtonItem *separator = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                                                               target:self 
                                                                               action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *action = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction 
                                                                            target:self 
                                                                            action:@selector(pressActionButton:)];
    [action setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];

    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:separator, addItem, action, nil] animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're hitting the code as you expect using a breakpoint on the `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem` line. Also, make sure that the myPopoverController property is declared strong if you're using arc, as otherwise it will be nil before the presenting line.

Comment: Yes, i am using ARC and popover property is strong. And i am sure code is hitting.

Answer (score 0):

The code is right.  Try replacing the sender with `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` or `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`. The sender may not be what you are expecting.

Also remove the if `(_mode == itemSelect)` clause for testing I'm  not sure why you need to access the ivar _mode ivar directly.

Comment: I am using _mode for toggle (edit mode/done button). I don't have nav controller, all UIBarButtonItems are laying in toolbar. Sender is as i linked him in Interface Builder

Comment: If its in the toolbar you'll need to use UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if `LookUpTableViewController *vc` actually gets a proper instance? If not then check that your storyboard does have `@"lookupTable"` set as your controller's identifier.

Comment: Yes, i did it. vc have proper instance